# Best usb storage for my router, Asus RT-AC66U?

Tags: wireless-router, usb-storage

I have the [ASUS RT-AC66U](http://www.asus.com/Networks/Wireless_Routers/RTAC66U/#specifications) and I want to add a USB storage to it. It has 2x USB, and Im already using one for my printer. So the last one I want to use to attach a USB storage, and I've read some reviews stating the throughput of the USB could be up to 18 mb/s.

So in regard of USB storage, should I care about hard disk cache?

Simple powered-over-usb seems to have 8 mb cache, other (externally powered) has 16 for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you are using it for? If it is just for backing up too then I would guess not. If it is for streaming off or loading files from then may be.

The fact it is on USB 2.0 also suggests not but your question seems to welcome debate and it is going to be very difficult to conclusively say yes or no I'm afraid (although I'm saying no :) )

Just as an aside, you may also want to consider NAS drives (if you don't know what they are).